# Vue.js: How to calculate total of an array field?

Tags: vue.js

I know that my question was asked a few times here, but I didn't find a working solution :(

My array in the data property is currently looking like this:

```
products: [{
    name: 'Product A',
    price: '10'
}, 
{
    name: 'Product B',
    price: '30'
}, 
{
    name: 'Product C',
    price: '20'
}]
```

Function to sum up the prices:

```
sumTotal() {
    let basket_total = [];
    this.products.forEach(val => {
        basket_total += val.price;
    });
    console.log(basket_total);
}
```

My result is `103020` instead of `60`. I also tried other ways, but every time I got the same result. What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: `basket_total` should be a number, not an array: `let basket_total = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , because you add this values as array items , you should do it :

```
sumTotal() {
    let basket_total = 0;
    this.products.forEach(val => {
        basket_total += Number(val.price);
       //or if you pass float numbers , use parseFloat()
    });
    console.log(basket_total);
}
```